# How to center html table?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

Trying to create proper PDF document, using PHP and TCPDF.

Can you help me, how can I use writeHTML function to create and center table, in TCPDF?

Tryed with:

```
 $html = '

 <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 50%">
  <table border="1" width="200" align="center"><tr><td><b>Invoice number: '.$this->xInvoiceNumber.'</b></td></tr></table>
  <br />
  <table border="1" width="200" align="center"><tr><td>'.$this->xClient.'</td></tr></table>
  <br />
 </div>
```

... but no luck.

Answer (score 16):

You have to make a table with 3 columns, set the width for every one of them and in the middle one you have to create your table.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width:25%"></td>
<td style="width:50%"><table><tr><td>Your content</td></tr></table></td>
<td style="width:25%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm not proud of this method but it's working :)

Comment: After trying a few things and failing bad, I am proud of you, even if you are not proud of yourself!  It is working for me - good job.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I don't know if there is solution for my problem...

However, I did manage to solve it by using writeHTMLCell funcion, ie.

```
$this->writeHTMLCell(50, 0, 50, 50, 'cellcontent', 'LRTB', 1, 0, true, 'L');
```

If somebody can find better solution, please reply.

Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code; it worked for me:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:30%">left margin</td>
    <td style="width:40%">
      <table border="1" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:100%" colspan="2"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="width:40%"><b></b></td>
            <td style="width:60%"><b></b></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width:30%">rigth margin</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello! As a heads up, questions and answers posted on Stack Overflow must be written in English. There is [a Spanish Stack Overflow](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) site being currently proposed that you may be interested in (after it goes live). _Hola! Como las cabezas para arriba, las preguntas y respuestas publicadas en desbordamiento de pila deben estar escritos en Inglés. Hay un sitio de desbordamiento español Pila está proponiendo actualmente que usted puede estar interesado en (después de que entre en vigor)_

Comment: Okey. sorry just help

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your opening div tag with this...

```
<div style="margin:5px auto; width:50%">
```

Answer (score 0):

Never done anything like this however, this is the code you would need to center a table that is the cross browser compatible

```
<div style="text:align:center;">
  <table style="margin:0px auto" border="1" width="200" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td><b>Invoice number: </b></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
  <table style="margin:0px auto"border="1" width="200" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>Client</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
</div>
```

If pdfs support css i would advise styling the html elements using css

```
table{
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:0px auto;
  text-align:center;
  width:200px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: well... with next code:

 <div style="text-align:center;">
   <table border="1" width="200" align="center">
     <tr>
       <td>
        <b>Invoice number: 123</b>
        <br />
        Invoice date: 2010-04-09
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <br />
 </div>

... text is centered, but borders of the table is aligned to left.

also, it would be nice if text can be aligned left in table... but i don't know is it possible...